# How to create an ajax call on jQuery slide change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

How do I call this Jquery ajax call on jQuery slide change?

```
function callpage() {
    $('#formcontent').empty().html('<p style="margin-top:20px;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;font-size:14px;">Vent venligst, henter webhosts.</p><p style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:center;"><img src="../images/ajax.gif" /></p>');
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success:function(msg){
            $('#formcontent').html(msg);
        }
    }
```

My jQuery slider code:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value:'',
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    step: 250,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == $(this).slider('option', 'max')) {
            $(ui.handle).html('Ubegrænset');
            $('#sliderValueplads').val('99999');
        } else {
            $(ui.handle).html(ui.value + ' MB');
            $('#sliderValueplads').val(ui.value);
        }
    }
}).find('a').html($('#slider').slider('value'));

$('#sliderValueplads').val($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

**My new slider code:**

```
        $("#slider").slider({
    value:'',
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    step: 250,
    stop: function(_, ui){
    callpage();
},
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == $(this).slider('option', 'max')) {
            $(ui.handle).html('Ubegrænset');
            $('#sliderValueplads').val('99999');
        } else {
            $(ui.handle).html(ui.value + ' MB');
            $('#sliderValueplads').val(ui.value);
        }
    }
}).find('a').html($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

The problem is that the ajax call is not made, but the HTML is replaced. Which is a little strange because I just have tested the callpage with this `$('#left input:checkbox').change(callpage);` and the callpage did work as expected

Comment: `var form = $(this).closest('form');` what is `this` referring to? if you call it from the slider it won't be what you think it is.

Comment: I want to get the form I have tried to give the form the ID search I have tried to say var form = $(this).closest('form#search'); but it does not work

Comment: I used var form = $('form#search'); and it did work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean when the user stops moving the slider then bind it to the stop event in your constructor.

```
stop: function(_, ui){
    callpage();
}
```

Comment: I will approve your answer. Do you know how to set the value to nothing?

Comment: The html is replaced but the ajax call is not made.

Comment: Strange I have testet the callpage with this: $('#left input:checkbox').change(callpage);    and it works fine. I have posted my new slider code.